# codeigniter seems not reusing model object

Tags: codeigniter

Typically, codeigniter uses below structrue.

```
class AController extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('ModelA');
        $this->load->model('ModelB');
        $this->load->model('ModelC');
        ...
    }
}
```

and I'm very new in codeigniter, I'm just wondering If I can make this more fast. Should I load these models whenever being made each request? It causes slow response.

In case of python tornado, they can store database model object so that all request share one model object. Is there any method like this in codeigniter?

Comment: You need to make sure that model is loaded once before you use it.

Comment: @ShaifulIslam thx, Could you tell me how to check it before using it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized the reusing is not possible, But I found better way.
something like this.

```
class AController extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $method = $this->router->fetch_method();
        switch($method) {
            case "method1":
                $this->load->model('ModelA');
            case "method2":
                $this->load->model('ModelB');
                break;
            default:
                $this->load->model('ModelA');
                $this->load->model('ModelC');
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure your model is loaded before using it.

1.You can write it inside Controllers construct function so that you don't need to load the model inside other method.As example

```
class AController extends CI_Controller
{
   public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('ModelA');
        $this->load->model('ModelB');
        $this->load->model('ModelC');
    }
    public function index()
    {
        $this->ModelA->model_funtion();//now you can call model function for m any function of controller.
    }
}
```

2.You can call it before using it.

```
class AController extends CI_Controller
{
   public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->model('ModelA');
        $this->ModelA->model_funtion();
    }
}
```

3.You can load inside autoload.php.So that model can be used everywhere(inside any controller).

Comment: Yes the construction is called with every request so if you need model in that controller you can load your model inside constructor.But remember write code the way I wrote.Your example code is wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it in ***most places***, but ***not in all places***, then as an alternative, you can create a Custom Controller and then Use it.

**1. Code for /application/core/Custom_Controller.php :**

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Custom_Controller extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('ModelA');
        $this->load->model('ModelB');
        $this->load->model('ModelC');
    }
}
```

**2. Then Extend the Controller as :**

```
include_once(APPPATH.'core/Custom_Controller.php');
class AController extends Custom_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    public function index()
    {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try it..

```
class AController extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('ModelA');
        $this->load->model('ModelB');
        $this->load->model('ModelC');
    }
    public functionname()
    {
        $this->ModelA->modelfunctionname();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add some details at your answer.Code only answer does not help that much to others.

Comment: Codeigniter controller write :
                                                                         class AController extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('ModelA');
        $this->load->model('ModelB');
        $this->load->model('ModelC');
    }
    public functionname()
    {
  //load any modelname
        $this->ModelA->modelfunctionname();   
  //load any viewpage may be you got it 
  $this->load->view('viewpage');
    }
}